# Tag Merge suggestions

Tags: discussion

Suggest merging the following tags:

- [Recording], [Audio Recording], [Recordings]
- [portable-recording],[field-recording]
- [film-mixing], [re-recording]

Suggest deleting the following tags:

- [fieldrecording]